# Now that ISFDB has (finally) turned on https, can we edit all relevant links in one fell swoop?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

ISFDB, [the Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi), is used in a *lot* of answers on this stack. It was notorious for not facilitating https. That has now been fixed, if I interpret [this related FAQ](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/index.php/ISFDB:FAQ#What_do_I_do_if_I_have_problems_logging_in.3F) correctly.

Ideally, we would now like all links to the ISFDB to use https instead of http as well. But there are a lot of links. *[A lot of links](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1683416/number-of-posts-with-links-to-isfdb).*

**Could this be handled by updating the db directly, as has been done in the past for similar situations?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the second link intended to point to the "problems logging in" question in that FAQ? Or is it meant to point to the question "Why do browsers say that the connection to ISFDB is not secure or that a Web page has "mixed content"?" (or to some other announcement)?

Comment: @V2Blast one assumes it is correct as that FAQ link shows that the site now uses HTTPS.

Comment: Someone could just write a bot to edit questions with their credentials, right? Unless there is some heavy-duty rate limiting going on, I think it should not be too difficult.

Comment: @Adamant or the Devs could make a single DB migration, which they've done before. Seems much simple.

Comment: But not *nearly* as fun.

Comment: @Adamant defiantly or indifferently we definitely define fun differently.

Comment: I can't seem to get access to their 'advanced search', even with a login.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, to "problems logging in" as that details the date of the change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for flagging this. All of these links have now been updated.

Comment: Ehr... I still see questions with http links to the ISFDB. Do I need to wait for the update to reach all corners of the stack?

Comment: @SQB Can you share the example? Maybe it still processing or something, I will check with our devs again.

Comment: [One](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59472/19561), [two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53447/19561), [three](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143150/19561).

Comment: Talked about this in chat with a mod. It seems as if inline links have been converted, while end-of-post lists if links haven't.

Comment: That's not super useful then because the automated editing tool creates end-of-post links.  And a fair number of users who hand-code their links _also_ use end-of-post links because it's cleaner.

Comment: @SQB I am checking with our dev team. Will follow up when I hear something back.

Comment: @SQB Alright, it should be good now. I double-checked, and they all appear to have been updated.

Comment: @SpencerG Awesome, thank you and the team!